# Hyper-V VLANS working, but VLAN trunk does not. Native VLAN works.. WEIRD,

Tags: hyper-v, vlan, trunk

Trying to get VLAN & Trunking to work in Hyper-V. 
I have two VM's on the same Network. SCVMM and Host1. Host1 should be a Trunk for VLAN 7-12 and Native VLAN 10. I then put SCVMM on VLAN7 via the GUI. Does not work! If I set Native Vlan to 7 it works. If I not use Trunking it works (both VMs on VLAN 7).

For some reason this site dont allow users to paste in formatted text so I have to Post a picture of the VLAN config...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4No6e.png)

What Am I doing wrong, or not understanding?
Its this LAB I am setting up.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/excellentsge/2016/10/06/deploying-sdn-on-one-single-physical-host-using-vmm/